# Фиолетовый терминал вывода в Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: visual-studio, mac

[image: Фиолетовый экран]

Доброго времени суток. После одного из последних обновлений вот так вот начал мне показывать терминал VS
кто нибудь сталкивался, как чинить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо установить [пакет](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions/releases), версии 0.31.1

Эта проблема [уже обсуждается на github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12077) несколько месяцев.