# фиолетовы экран в терминале Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, mac

Вместо результатов в терминале в Visual Studio на Mac, у меня просто фиолетовый экран, как можно решить эту проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1470183/312941

Comment: там нету решения этой проблемы(